# How to deal with questions that are useless without their tags?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

Occasionally a question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14496721/507519) pops up, where a critical part of the question resides in the tags - in this case the name of the tool in use by the questioner.

From my perspective, tags should be used to facilitate searching and post grouping - not to convey significant pieces of information, especially since their use is often quite inconsistent.

Is there a consensus regarding this use of tags?

If it is indeed not desirable, what would the proper response be to such a question - especially if the questioner does not update it with the needed context?

1. *Downvoting*: One would think that questions with this problem are usually of quite low quality anyway, so downvoting is probably warranted.
2. *Closing as 'Not a real question', with a possible deletion afterwards*: For one, if you miss the tag then the question itself makes no sense. And even if you do not miss it, the question could easily stop making sense six months or a year from now if the tag is used inconsistently.

   Not to mention that if you need to use Google to understand what *planet* the question is coming from then it is probably not a real question anyway...
3. *Flagging for low quality and letting the review system handle it*
4. Any combination of the above...

Comment: You can add the context yourself with an edit too. You have the reputation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Perhaps I could in this case, since Google only finds *one* Bullseye Code-coverage tool, but I generally avoid guessing like this, especially when I am not familiar with the tool in question. For all I know even such a minor edit could distort the original meaning of the question and mislead those that *are* more familiar with the subject...

Comment: Then, unless the question looks like an obvious NARQ to you, leave it be. If noone else comes along that does understand the question, it'll die a quiet low-view-no-votes death on it's own.

Comment: Rule of thumb: A question which consists of one line should be thrown into the snake pit!

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [What should I write in the question body if the title already explains everything?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145019/what-should-i-write-in-the-question-body-if-the-title-already-explains-everythin)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you understnad the question, edit it for clarity like you would for any other problem (e.g. formatting).

If you don't understand the question, comment asking for clarification.

Optionally, if this is a pattern with that poster, also downvote to provide some motivation to fix it.  But in that case you should come back and reverse that if he actually does fix it.