# Double entity encoding in suggested duplicate list

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

While reviewing a suggested close vote, one option was to resolve as duplicate of [How can I parse XML using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722140/how-can-i-parse-xml-using-java). This question starts with a code block of XML source, however the summary of the question in the list of suggested duplicates showed the source `&lt;` and `&gt;` entities rather than `<` and `>` characters, so it looked as if they were getting encoded twice.

E.g:

> [image]

Answer (score 8):

Reproduced. To clarify, this only occurs in the alternate list that shows up when there are already suggested duplicates on the question. Using the search box does not create the error.

**Default view with suggested duplicates:**

> [image: Default View]

**Searching for the same question:**

> [image: Search View]

And of course, the [lucky review item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/1919524) that let me reproduce this.

---

Code is *supposed* to get completely stripped there. It shouldn't even reach the stage of being encoded. Obviously that is not being done for the first view.

Answer (score 2):

This problem still exists for me. While marking a question as a duplicate, [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145019/what-should-i-write-in-the-question-body-if-the-title-already-explains-everythin) got suggested as a possible duplicate. The first character seems to be double-encoded, while the last character is fine.

[image: First character double-encoded]