# Should we explicitly repeat the content of the title in the question?

Tags: discussion

Shouldn't it be mandatory for the question body to actually contain the question irrespective of the fact it is mentioned in the title?

It has happened several times that I go through a question, and after reading I ask myself "what's the question?". The title usually goes into volatile memory and if the question contains a long description by the end the reading it evaporates.

Comment: Hmm.. so one might say that it's ok to have a question without a title?

Comment: @devnull why would they? Titles are important.

Comment: And redundancy is important too?

Comment: @devnull It is not necessary for it by completely redundant. It could be somewhat detailed version of that in the title. And doesn't matter if it is redundant the question body should stand on its own irrespective of the title, whether it contains the question or a summary of it.

Comment: The answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145022/238020 explains all.

Comment: Presumably all an algorithm could do is ensure that an identical sentence was in the body; which is non ideal. I agree with the sentiment though

Comment: @Bart that's not a duplicate. A question could well have lots of stuff in the body and yet fail to convey the whole question in the body

Comment: @JanDvorak What am I missing here? What makes this not a duplicate?

Comment: @Bart Title: 'How do I foo the bar using baz?' Body: 'I know I can foo the bar using quux, but quux is expensive. I have also tried xyzzy, but it's too slow, and rabba doesn't handle bafoor correctly'. This question is whether 'Can I use baz to foo the bar?' needs to be appended to the body. The linked question and its answers are only concerned about the specific case where the body would otherwise be empty. Your answer does hint that this is true, but I feel it should be stated explicitly. I didn't notice the hint at first or at second. Also, the question itself doesn't mention that case.

Comment: Ah @JanDvorak I think the first paragraph here tripped me up. So the question is really "Should we explicitly repeat the content of the title in the question?". Myeah. Vote to reopen.

Comment: The opposite question is related too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66119/title-only-questions-i-e-questions-without-body-should-be-allowed/109403#109403