# Are one sentence questions allowed on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

I was about to ask a question on a Stack Exchange site but I didn't have any details to put in the body so I was deciding to post the question with just one sentence. Is that an OK thing to do on the Stack Exchange network or should I somehow find details for my question before I post it?

Comment: Highly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145019/what-should-i-write-in-the-question-body-if-the-title-already-explains-everythin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are one sentence questions allowed on Stack Exchange?

Yes...

***BUT!***

That one sentence *must* form a good question based on the quality standards of the site. Beyond a minimum character check, there aren't really any specific question *length* requirements, just *quality* requirements.

While I won't say it's impossible for a single-sentence question to be a decent question on some SE sites, such a thing would certainly not be the norm. There is some correlation between extremely-short questions and low-quality or unresearched questions.

Instead of focusing on length, focus on the quality of your post. Is it clear what it asks? Can it be answers in a reasonably-lengthed answer? Does it show your research (if applicable to the SE site)? Is there more information you can give potential answerers? The help center for the site you are asking on often has some hints on creating good questions.